# Why does jQuery seem to be queuing my ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, queue

I'm trying to implement a messaging system into my PHP site using long-polling with jQuery. However, whenever I try to send a message while it's listening for new messages, it seems to be waiting for it to finish listening before executing the send message script, resulting in a Firebug console similar to the following:

[image: Firebug loading]

Both stop at the same time, which, considering the second (send message) call literally takes no time at all to execute when the other script isn't running, leads me to believe my send message script is waiting for my polling loop to complete. The following is my PHP (with some non-essential code eliminated for security purposes), and JavaScript, for long-polling. I'd post message sending, but all it does is insert a value into the database.

Long-polling

```
$ml = message_len($id); //Gets number of messages
$start_length   = $ml;
$current_length = $ml;
$timeout = 0;

while( $current_length <= $start_length )
{
    sleep(1);
    clearstatcache();
    $current_length = message_len($id);
    $timeout++;
    if($timeout>29)
    {
        echo $current_length;
        exit;
        break;
    }
}

$info = getInfo(); //Gets message array
echo $info;
```

JavaScript:

```
function message_listen()
{
     ajaxListener = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/scripts/php/method/exchange/listen.php", 
        data: { "id" : offerid },
        cache: false,
        success:
            function(data)
            { 
                    /* Do something with the data */

                setTimeout("message_listen()", 1000);
            }
    });
}
```

The ajax call for message sending looks like this:

```
function message_send(message)
{
    //msgid is defined elsewhere
    $.get("/api/sendmsg.php", { "id" : msgid, "message" : message }, function(data) { document.getElementById("txtbx").value=""; } );
}
```

Please note that these are two separate files that are being called. No matter what I try, the files execute concurrently and stop at the same exact time. I need the message to send on it's own time, have the listener detect that, then return the messages when the new message has been sent. Has something like this ever happened to anyone else? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Your code,

JavaScript:

```
function message_listen()
{
     ajaxListener = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/scripts/php/method/exchange/listen.php", 
        data: { "id" : offerid },
        cache: false,
        success:
            function(data)
            { 
                    /* Do something with the data */

                setTimeout("message_listen()", 1000);
            }
    });
}
```

Apply,

cache: true

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by following this post: http://lucadaniel.ro/2013/01/27/concurrent-ajax-requests-and-php/